# Как в python 3.5 из даты получить timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime, timestamp

Есть дата, которая имеет формат :   `'Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:23:49 GMT'` , как из этой даты можно получить `timestamp`?

Comment: Исходная дата принимается как string?

Comment: в какой часовой зоне у вас вторая дата?

Comment: @jfs Может быть в любом часовом поясе, дата высчитывается по времени customer-a(отдается с фронтенда `AJAX`-ом), и высчитывается только день/месяц/год

Comment: @Klimenkomud: "в любом часовом поясе" означает, что время известно с точностью до +- день. Может всё-таки не в любом?

Comment: @jfs Нет, время может быть именно в любом часовом поясе, т.к. вычисляется не на сервере, а на клиенте( который потенциально может прибывать в любом уголке мира), и впринципе такое сравнение необходимо для того, чтобы понять что действия, произведенные на клиенте произошли в один день, чтобы потом их сложить скопом. Так что в рамках одного клиента будет действовать один часовой пояс, соответственно точность сравнения(по идее) будет высока.

Comment: учитывая, что часовые зоны это не простая тема, вам следует разделить вопросы: "как дату из строки в timestamp превратить", "как распознать заданный формат даты", "что такое GMT и как к UTC это относится", "стоит ли на сервере доверять дате, присланной клиентом",  "может ли часовая зона на клиенте отличаться от UTC и насколько дней"

Comment: ещё можно сделать шаг назад и посмотреть какую вы вообще задачу пытаетесь решить (какой контекст). Может стоит спросить (как новый вопрос): "как передать время в клиентской часовой зоне на сервер (Питон) из javascript" или вообще "как действия пользователя, сгруппировать по (клиентским) дням" См. [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дата в таком формате используется в почтовых сообщениях ([rfc 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822.html)), чтобы её распознать можно использовать [email модуль из стандартной библиотеки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate_to_datetime):

```
>>> from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime
>>> parsedate_to_datetime('Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:23:49 GMT')
datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 30, 12, 23, 49, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> _.timestamp()
1504095829.0
```

> дата у меня другого формата: 2017-06-26 17:10:20.619328+03:00

Это [rfc 3339 формат](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6). В Python 3.7+:

```
>>> import datetime as DT
>>> DT.datetime.fromisoformat('2017-08-30 15:23:49+03:00').timestamp()
1504095829.0
```

Comment: А это стандартная библиотека?

Comment: А не из консоли, а просто в скрипте это будет выглядеть как `date = parsedate_to_time('Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:23:49 GMT').timestamp()` ,правильно?

Comment: Получаю вот такую штуку `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: @Klimenkomud: код в моём ответе и код в вашем комментарии не может эту ошибку выбросить. [Создайте минимальный, но полный пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который к этой ошибке ведёт и опубликуйте его как отдельный вопрос ("вычисляя X, получаю ошибку Y")

Comment: @Klimenkomud: ответ содержит **полный** пример кода. То есть сперва необходимо сделать импорт, а потом  parsedate_to_time().timestamp() вызывать.

Comment: `import` сделал, попробую вынести проблему в отдельный вопрос

Comment: Нашел ошибку, дата у меня другого формата: `2017-06-26 17:10:20.619328+03:00`, поправлю сейчас вопрос

Answer (score 2):

[Dateutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.6.1)

```
from dateutil import parser

s = 'Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:23:49 GMT'
ts = parser.parse(s).timestamp()
```

Comment: `dateutil.parser()` много форматов распознаёт и может иногда гадать в расплывчатых случаях -- молча принять неверную строку. В данном случае, stdlib достаточно.

Answer (score 1):

На 2.7 работает, на тройке, по идее тоже должно.

```
import datetime, time
s="Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:23:49 GMT"
print(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%a, %d %b %Y %X %Z").timetuple())) # выводит timestamp
print(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(c, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())) #выводит timestamp
```

Comment: это неверно. `mktime()` ожидает локальное время, которое не обязано совпадать с UTC.